# PHP file_get_contents and explode not working properly with if statement

Tags: php

I have a file called tracker.txt that contains 3 lines. The txt file is this: http://tracker.cpcheats.co/rookie/tracker.txt. I am using file_get_contents and explode to return each line of the array, like so:

```
$read = file_get_contents('tracker.txt');
$filed = explode("\n",$read);
$status = $filed[0];
$server = $filed[1];
$room = $filed[2];
```

I then have an if statement, where the condition is if the first line of tracker.txt ($status) is 'found', then it will write out the second and third line onto the image. It doesn't work.

```
if ($status == 'found') {
//write out the server room and language (with shadow)
imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 140, 80, $white, $font, $server);
imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 139, 79, $black, $font, $server);
imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 140, 105, $white, $font, $room);
imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 139, 104, $black, $font, $room);
}
```

The odd thing is, if I just print out $status, $server and $room without the if statement, it works fine and dispays the correct lines. Why isn't it working with the condition? Because, I'm sure the first line of http://tracker.cpcheats.co/rookie/tracker.txt is 'found'.

Comment: Does the file use DOS-style newlines (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)? i.e., are there trailing `\r` characters at the end of each line before the `\n` you're exploding on?

Comment: Just before the first block of code I gave you, I have this. `$file = fopen("tracker.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,"found\n (EN) Avalanche\nIce Berg");
fclose($file);`

Comment: PHP also has the [`file()`](http://php.net/file) function, which reads the file and returns all lines in an array already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `trim` to remove empty white space

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://tracker.cpcheats.co/rookie/tracker.txt");
$string = explode("\n", $string);
list($status, $server, $room) = array_map("trim", $string);
```

Before trim

```
array
  0 => string 'found
' (length=6)
  1 => string ' (EN) Avalanche
' (length=16)
  2 => string 'Ice Berg' (length=8)
```

// After Trim

```
array
  0 => string 'found' (length=5)
  1 => string '(EN) Avalanche' (length=14)
  2 => string 'Ice Berg' (length=8)
```

Can you see that the length is of `$status` is different `length=6`  and `length=5` respectively

You can also just do

```
if (trim($status) == 'found') {
    // .... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra \r. This works:

```
if ($status == "found\r"){
   ...
}
```